# error running ghdl sample dlx implementation

Tags: vhdl, ghdl, dlx

I am learning VHDL using GHDL. I am following GHDL tutorial from here: https://ghdl.github.io/ghdl/quick_start/simulation/DLXModelSuite.html

when I run this command:

```
ghdl -r --workdir=work dlx_test_behaviour
```

I am getting this error:

```
dlx_test_behaviour.vhdl:34:3: architecture "bench" of "dlx_test" is obsoleted by package "dlx_types"
  for bench
  ^
dlx_test_behaviour.vhdl:42:23: entity "memory" is obsoleted by package "mem_types"
      use entity work.memory(behaviour)
                      ^
dlx_test_behaviour.vhdl:48:23: entity "dlx_bus_monitor" is obsoleted by package "dlx_types"
      use entity work.dlx_bus_monitor(behaviour)
                      ^
dlx_test_behaviour.vhdl:53:23: entity "dlx" is obsoleted by package "dlx_types"
      use entity work.dlx(behaviour)
                      ^
*command line*:1:1: configuration "dlx_test_behaviour" is obsoleted by entity "memory"

^
*command line*:1:1: configuration "dlx_test_behaviour" is obsoleted by architecture "bench" of "dlx_test"

^
dlx_types.vhdl:32:9: package body "dlx_types" is outdated
package dlx_types is
        ^
bv_arithmetic.vhdl:41:9: package body "bv_arithmetic" is outdated
package bv_arithmetic is
        ^
images.vhdl:36:9: package body "images" is outdated
package images is
        ^
dlx_bus_monitor-behaviour.vhdl:33:10: package "dlx_instr" is obsoleted by package "dlx_types"
    work.dlx_instr.all,
         ^
dlx_test_behaviour.vhdl:48:11: architecture "behaviour" of "dlx_bus_monitor" is obsoleted by package "dlx_instr"
      use entity work.dlx_bus_monitor(behaviour)
          ^
dlx_test_behaviour.vhdl:48:11: architecture "behaviour" of "dlx_bus_monitor" is obsoleted by package "dlx_instr"
      use entity work.dlx_bus_monitor(behaviour)
          ^
dlx_bus_monitor-behaviour.vhdl:37:14: architecture "behaviour" of "dlx_bus_monitor" is obsoleted by package "dlx_instr"
architecture behaviour of dlx_bus_monitor is
             ^
dlx_instr.vhdl:32:1: package body "dlx_instr" is obsoleted by package "dlx_instr"
use std.textio.line,
^
dlx_test_behaviour.vhdl:53:11: architecture "behaviour" of "dlx" is obsoleted by package "dlx_instr"
      use entity work.dlx(behaviour)
          ^
dlx_test_behaviour.vhdl:53:11: architecture "behaviour" of "dlx" is obsoleted by package "dlx_instr"
      use entity work.dlx(behaviour)
          ^
dlx-behaviour.vhdl:37:14: architecture "behaviour" of "dlx" is obsoleted by package "dlx_instr"
architecture behaviour of dlx is
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?